# Data-labels not displaying in proper order with excel scattered chart using vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel sheet with master data with the following information

Row number | candidate | X Value | Y value

I need to plot a scattered chart with X and Y value plotted with row number as data label. Created a VBA to do so, and it worked but datalabel was overlapping. It was fixed with the help of one of our member. But the issue now is, some of the datapoint is showing in different points.

[Error picture here, please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8urd4.jpg)

Code as follows

```
Dim Counter As Integer, ChartName As String, xVals As String, yVals As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim c As ChartObject
Set c = Sheets("IImpactchart").ChartObjects("Chart 1")
c.Activate

'Find address of the X values
xVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
xVals = Mid(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, ","), xVals, _
    Mid(Left(xVals, InStr(xVals, "!") - 1), 9)))
xVals = Left(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, "!"), xVals, ",") - 1)

'Not sure why this loop from your code is useful, but let's leave it.
Do While Left(xVals, 1) = ","
    xVals = Mid(xVals, 2)
Loop

'Find address of the Y values
yVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
yVals = Mid(yVals, InStr(InStr(yVals, ","), yVals, _
    Mid(Left(yVals, InStr(yVals, "!") - 1), 9)))
yVals = Right(yVals, Len(yVals) - InStr(yVals, ","))
yVals = Left(yVals, InStr(InStr(yVals, "!"), yVals, ",") - 1)

'Again, not sure why this loop from your code is useful, but let's leave it.
Do While Left(yVals, 1) = ","
    yVals = Mid(yVals, 2)
Loop

Dim DimY As Long, DimX As Long
DimY = 250
DimX = 250

Dim LabelArray() As Long
ReDim LabelArray(1 To DimX, 1 To DimY)

Dim src As Series, pts As Points
Set src = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
Set pts = src.Points

'Clear labels
src.HasDataLabels = False
For Counter = 1 To Range(xVals).Cells.Count
    If (Range(xVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value = 0) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim xCoord As Long, yCoord As Long
    xCoord = Range(xVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Value2
    yCoord = Range(yVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Value2


    If LabelArray(xCoord, yCoord) = 0 Then 'No overlap
        LabelArray(xCoord, yCoord) = Counter
        pts(Counter).HasDataLabel = True
        pts(Counter).DataLabel.Text = Counter + 5
    Else 'Overlap
        pts(LabelArray(xCoord, yCoord)).DataLabel.Text = _
            pts(LabelArray(xCoord, yCoord)).DataLabel.Text & "," & Counter + 5
    End If
Next Counter

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Solved... issue with yCoord = Range(yVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Value2.  changed to yCoord = Range(yVals).Cells(Counter, 2).Value2

Comment: Yeah done that @QHarr  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above issue was solved by changing

```
yCoord = Range(yVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Value2
```

to

```
yCoord = Range(yVals).Cells(Counter, 2).Value2
```